# SL 4 converstion To WPF help

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight-4.0

I have this code block in SL4, Can anyone help me to convert this to WPF 4

grate help thanks in advance,

```
    <Grid x:Name="UXLearn" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
     <Grid.Projection>
       <PlaneProjection LocalOffsetZ="40" />
     </Grid.Projection>
     <Grid.RenderTransform>
       <CompositeTransform ScaleX="0.96" ScaleY="0.96" />
     </Grid.RenderTransform>
     <TextBlock Margin="0,-110,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Learn Expression Blend" FontFamily="Fonts/Fonts.zip#Segoe WP Light" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FFFB8917">
       <TextBlock.Projection>
         <PlaneProjection />
       </TextBlock.Projection>
     </TextBlock>
   </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are only using ScaleX and ScaleY, you should be able to replace CompositeTransform with ScaleTransform.

For Grid.Projection, take a look at [ViewPort3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewport3d.aspx).